# Zend framework 2 \Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet->toArray() doe not return records

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm simply trying to fetch all records in a given table by extending Zend `AbstractTableGateway` and making use of inherited `select()` function. this `select()` function returns type Zend `ResultSet` however I'm not able get an array of results using `toArray()`.

I get the following message:

> Rows as part of this DataSource, with type object cannot be cast to an array

### Update

I worked it out

assuming you have extended AbstractTableGateway

```
$resultSet = $this->select();
foreach($resultSet as $row) { echo $row->yourProperty }
```

Comment: Zend_Db_Result is already having a toArray(). could you please paste your code for reference.http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.0/classes/Zend.Db.ResultSet.ResultSet.html

Comment: FYI: if you are using a custom array object prototype in the result set, adding a toArray() method to your entity will fix this

Answer (score 6):

You should use `HydratingResultSet` like this :

```
class MyClassTable extends AbstractTableGateway
{
    public function __construct(Adapter $adapter)
{
    $this->adapter = $adapter;
    $this->resultSetPrototype = new HydratingResultSet();
    $this->resultSetPrototype->setObjectPrototype(new MyClass());
    $this->initialize();
}

public function fetchAll()
{
    $resultSet = $this->select();
    return $resultSet;
}

public function fetchAllToArray()
{
    $aData = $this->fetchAll()->toArray();
    return $aData;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also try this

```
$sql = new Sql($adapter);

$select = $sql->select();

$select->from('table');

$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select); 

$results = $statement->execute();

$resultSet = new ResultSet();
$resultSet->initialize($results);

print_r($resultSet->toArray());
```

With Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;

Answer (score 3):

Just try to use

```
(array)$resultSet
```

I've used this sometimes on ZF and works fine.

Comment: Awesome shortcut. This has saved me a ton of time.

Answer (score 2):

Mine issue was as @Fatmuemoo noted.

If you register your custom object prototype, code eg.

```
$resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet($entityClassName, new $entityClassName);
$instance->setResultSetPrototype($resultSetPrototype);
```

you have to implement **toArray()** method in yout Entity class.

```
public function toArray()
{
    return get_object_vars($this);
}
```